vuejs $refs does not work when component has import for another component
My Web Console says:
TypeError: this.$refs.smile.sayHi is not a function
First i created a vuejs project:

Add a src/components/Smile.vue
<template>
  <h1>Smile</h1>
</template>

Add another src/components/BigSmile.vue
<script setup>
  import Smile from './Smile.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Big</h1>
  <Smile/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    sayHi:function() { alert('Hi babe'); }
  }
}
</script>

And edit src/components/TheWelcome.vue into:
<script setup>
import BigSmile from './BigSmile.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <BigSmile ref="smile"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted:function() {
    this.$refs.smile.sayHi();
  }
}
</script>

If i change src/components/BigSmile.vue into:
<script setup>
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Big</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods:{
    sayHi:function() { alert('Hi babe'); }
  }
}
</script>

Suddenly it works.
I want to be able to $refs with nested SFC components. Is it possible?

This is a side effect of mixing <script> and <script setup> tags incorrectly and unnecessarily.

Please choose one vue API style composition or options dont use both for components because the refs will target the composition first.

<script setup> is composition
<script> is options

Reference about vue API styles documentation
Example in composition API src/components/BigSmile.vue
<template>
  <h1>Big</h1>
  <Smile />
</template>

<script setup>
import Smile from './Smile.vue';

const sayHi = () => { alert('Hi babe'); };
</script>

Example in options API src/components/BigSmile.vue
<template>
  <h1>Big</h1>
  <Smile />
</template>

<script>
import Smile from './Smile.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Smile
  },
  methods: {
    sayHi() {
      alert('Hi babe');
    }
  },
}
</script>

Hope that helps.
